# How to integrate $\int_0^{\theta}\frac{x}{(1-x^2)(1-x)}dx$?

Tags: integration

> How to integrate  $\displaystyle\int_0^{\theta}\frac{x}{(1-x^2)(1-x)}dx$ ?
>
> If $\theta\in(0,\frac{1}{2})$

$$
\begin{align}
& \int_0^{\theta}\frac{x}{(1-x^2)(1-x)}\,dx \\[8pt]
= & \int_0^{\theta}\frac{x}{(1-x)(1+x)(1-x)}\,dx \\[8pt]
= & \int_0^{\theta}\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\frac{x}{1+x}dx \\[8pt]
= & \int_0^{\theta}\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\Big(1-\frac{1}{1+x}\Big) \, dx \\[8pt]
= & \int_0^{\theta}\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}-\displaystyle\int_0^{\theta}\frac{1}{(1-x^2)(1-x)} \, dx
\end{align}
$$

LHS is OK, but RHS ?

Comment: Partial fractions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about partial fraction decomposition?

$$\begin{align} \displaystyle\int_0^{\theta}\frac{x}{(1-x^2)(1-x)}dx & = \int_0^\theta \frac x{(1-x)(1+x)(1 - x)} \,dx \\ \\ & = \int_0^\theta \frac x{(1+x)(1-x)^2}dx \\ \\ & = \int_0^\theta \left[ \frac A{1+x} + \frac B{1-x} + \frac C{(1-x)^2}\right]dx\end{align}$$

Comment: You only have two factors: $(1 + x)$ and $(1 - x)$, but your final denominator is supposed to be $(1 + x)(1 - x)^2$, so you need a fraction with $1/(1 - x)^2$.  Now think about the fact that $A$ is going to have a quadratic term (from multiplying by $(1 - x)^2$).  If you only had $C/(1 - x)^2$, the $C$ would only be multiplied by $(1 + x)$ which does _not_ give a quadratic term.  By putting in the extra $B/(1 - x)$ (which needs an extra $(1 - x)$ _and_ $(1 + x)$) you can cancel that quadratic term with $B$.  You could also have done $\frac{A}{1 + x} + \frac{Bx + C}{(1 - x)^2}$.

Comment: @Jared Ok i remembered we want no $''x''$ in the denominator

Comment: @Jared I have exactly that: Were you addressing the OP or me?

Comment: @amWhy The OP had a comment here that I guess was deleted, I was answering that question.  Just trying to explain why you need those three terms, not just two which is a common mistake.  Which, btw, is why you should _not_ just plug in $x = 1$ and solve for $A$ and $B$ (although if you have the proper form, with the $C$ here, that would work).

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for editing in the missing "dx's"!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

The partial fraction decomposition is:
$$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2(1+x)}=\frac{1}{4(x-1)}-\frac{1}{4(x+1)}+\frac{1}{2(x-1)^2}$$

Comment: How did you see that ?

Comment: Do you know the partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: Yes, then just compare the coefficients, right ?

Comment: Denote the given fraction $F(x)$ then *for example* the third  coefficient is 
$$F(x)(x-1)^2\bigg|_{x=1}=\frac12$$

Comment: what is that, an easier method ?